# Automatically generate "Reference leaflet" and Pedagogical book

Tags: document-classes, document-configuration

I am writing a book on math, and I would like to support two ways to read it :

The usual, **pedagogical** way, to write is in sequential, topological order :

- we introduce an operation
- we introduce a theorem
- we explicit the impact of the theorem on operations ("properties", like equations)
- we introduce a new operation
- etc. ...

At any point during the reading, the only notions used are the one previously introduced.

The other way is the **reference** book :

- We define an operation
- We expose all (or a subset of) the properties this operation is involved in

So that we might invoke theorems which are not yet defined to justify those

Is there a way to write once, but automatically support the generation of both style without rewriting ?

Comment: Can you please add a brief textual example to your question, which illustrates both ways? And how a one-source-only approach might look like for said example?

Comment: Put all the proofs into appendices?  Hypertext the heck out of it?